# Storing Dataset in .xpt File

Tags: c#, .net, sas

I am trying to find out how to store data which I retrieved from an SQL server to a `.xpt` file.

Can anyone please help me to do this with C#?

Comment: Thank you @Addison

Comment: .XPT  for Mozilla Firefox Component?

Comment: Clients requirement is to store the database tables in XPT file

Comment: XPT is a proprietary SAS format, AFAIK there isn't a library that does that. Do you have access to SAS and want to execute the correct SAS commands from C#?

Answer (score 0):

The `.xpt` filename extension is often used for files created by `Proc CPORT`. The files contain SAS transport formatted data which can be read back in by `Proc CIMPORT` code run in other SAS installations.

Sample Code

```
* transport a data set;
proc cport data=sashelp.class file='%temp%\class.xpt';
run;

* transport the results of a query;
proc sql;
  create view for_transport as
  select * from sashelp.class
  ;

proc cport data=work.for_transport file='%temp%\myquery_resultset.xpt';
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Time and money might be better spent on changing the requirement to 'create .xml' file instead of 'create .xpt' file.

- `.XPT` file is going to be read by a SAS session.
- There is no C# library for creating .XPT
- You would have to decipher .XPT and test a roll your own .XPT writer
- SAS sessions can also read .XML files.
- SQL Server has super convenient `FOR XML` clause that creates xml output
  directly
- Very easy to execute SQL server code from C#
- Client gets .xml file, that can be readily read into their SAS systems

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by XPT you mean SAS V5 Transport files, there is this C library for reading (and writing) multiple statistical formats, including SAS's XPORT format.

https://github.com/WizardMac/ReadStat

Not sure if it is compatible with C#.